# Wrapper Class for Account or Contact history record

Tags: apex, soql, standard-objects, accounthistory

I have a requirement to show a account and contact changes in lwc.

I am trying to create a GenericHistoryRecord wrapper class with 2 constructors.
If Account record is being updated then call constructor for Account and if Contact record is updated then call constructor for Contact record.

Attributes that should be created on this class are:

CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, NewValue, OldValue

so that I could get a list of HistoryRecords for Accounts and Contacts in one collection and be able to display these in LWC.

Could you help me with creating the wrapper class?
What I have so far:

```
`public  with sharing class HistoryRecordWrapper {
Id CreatedById;
Datetime CreatedDate;
Picklist Field;
AnyType NewValue;
AnyType OldValue;


//2 constructors - one for each record 
public HistoryRecordWrapper(AccountHistory accHistory) {
    CreatedById = accHistory.CreatedById;
    CreatedDate = accHistory.CreatedDate;
}

public HistoryRecordWrapper(ContactHistory conHistory) {
    CreatedById = conHistory.CreatedById;
    CreatedDate = conHistory.CreatedDate;
}
```

}

I am not sure how to handle Field, NewValue and OldValue

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to show us what you've written so far.

Comment: It looks like you've already drawn on what's available for ["Object History" records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_associated_objects_history.htm). For `anyType` you can use `Object` or, perhaps easier to handle, represent all your values as `String` since they should all be convertible to Strings. From there, your requirements will really drive what you need to do. For example, Lookups are going to be Ids, but these won't be user-friendly unless you fetch the "DisplayName" for the lookup and hyperlink it.